# Tokenize a string using multiple conditions

Tags: c#, regex

For the string below:

```
var str = "value0 'value 1/5' 'x ' value2";
```

Is there a way I can parse that string such that I get

```
arr[0] = "value0";
arr[1] = "value 1/5";
arr[2] = "x ";
arr[3] = "value2";
```

The order of values that might come with single quotes is arbitrary. Case does not matter.

I can get all values between single quotes using a regex like

```
"'(.*?)'"
```

but I need the order of those values relative other non-single-quoted values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```cs
'(?<val>.*?)'|(?<val>\S+)
```

See [regex proof](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%27%28%3F%3Cval%3E.*%3F%29%27%7C%28%3F%3Cval%3E%5CS%2B%29&i=value0%20%27value%201%2F5%27%20%27x%20%27%20value2)

**EXPLANATION**

```cs
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  '                        '\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  '                        '\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
```

**[C# code](https://tio.run/##XVDLTsMwELz7K1a5OKZgHhKnAEVCFRd6oQgOwMENS7HkOJbXroKg3x4ctzSIOXg03p31rGs6qluPfR9J2xUsPilgU7G/Sj5gF@Q9rqJRftY5j0S6tVQx5uLS6Bpqo4hg1qnGGWRfDBJ2JQoqJFq3@g3mSttS5Oq2ZwAFPzzlVAjoLVzCdcHL6cVamSt5MBX8eydeFhNRVP9t2roYsin1RDwBnhlOj8858A44ZH02OvcT3tPaqv6Acq5CoibNgrQkdjJfIJV5@OFvNCH21jH9gJv0F61B@eR1wDttsWzkrW@jo@chVfEqH4cMYgy/Ydtz0/c/)**:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"'(?<val>.*?)'|(?<val>\S+)";
        string input = @"value0 'value 1/5' 'x ' value2";
        
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["val"].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can reuse the same named capture group, so you could use an alternation `|` using the same group name for both parts.

```
'(?<val>[^']+)'|(?<val>\S+)
```

The pattern matches:

- `'` Match a single quote
- `(?<val>[^']+)` Capture in group **val** matching 1+ times any char except `'` to not match an empty string
- `'` Match a single quote
- `|` Or
- `(?<val>\S+)` Capture in group **val** matching 1+ times any non whitespace char

See a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%27%28%3f%3cval%3e%5b%5e%27%5d%2b%29%27%7c%28%3f%3cval%3e%5cS%2b%29&i=value0+%27value+1%2f5%27+%27x+%27+value2) or a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/uJhcza)

[image]

For example

```
string pattern = @"'(?<val>[^']+)'|(?<val>\S+)";
var str = "value0 'value 1/5' 'x ' value2";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(str, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["val"].Value);
}
```

Output

```
value0
value 1/5
x 
value2
```